# How can I format following javascript arrays data in c3js?

Tags: c3.js

I have to display the following data in a c3js multi-line chart.
The date will be the x axis.
each row will be each line in the chart.
When I try to display this in multi line chart it doesn't display and also not giving any error.
Please help me.

```
 ["date", "2017-05-01", "2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", "2017-05-04", "2017-05-06", "2017-05-08", "2017-05-09", "2017-05-10", "2017-05-12", "2017-05-13", "2017-05-16", "2017-05-17", "2017-05-18", "2017-05-19", "2017-05-20", "2017-05-23", "2017-05-24", "2017-05-25", "2017-05-29"]["Shrirang Adkar", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Delhi Store", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Ajay Subramaniam", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Shivani Yadavalli", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Siddhesh 2020", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Salva", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Iranna Zampa", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Hisam", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] ["Samruddhi Sawant", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Manish K S", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] ["Sukanya Ray", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Karen Ho", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Srishti Narang", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Sreejata Mitra", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]["Estroz", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: Put your code to jsfiddle and provide a link. You can use this example as a starting point: http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sala/dc1d7a7g/1/). You need to put `,` between every chunk of datas.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'date',
        columns: [
             ["date", "2017-05-01", "2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", "2017-05-04", "2017-05-06", "2017-05-08", "2017-05-09", "2017-05-10", "2017-05-12", "2017-05-13", "2017-05-16", "2017-05-17", "2017-05-18", "2017-05-19", "2017-05-20", "2017-05-23", "2017-05-24", "2017-05-25", "2017-05-29"],
             ["Shrirang Adkar", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Delhi Store", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Ajay Subramaniam", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Shivani Yadavalli", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Siddhesh 2020", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Salva", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Iranna Zampa", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Hisam", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Samruddhi Sawant", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Manish K S", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Sukanya Ray", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Karen Ho", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Srishti Narang", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Sreejata Mitra", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
             ["Estroz", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```